# Is infinite VC-dim equivalent to universal approximator?

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

If $m$ is the VC-dim then it means there is no configuration of $m+1$ datapoints we can shatter. But there could be configurations of $m$ datapoints we cannot shatter. Hence my confusion and my question:

*Is having an infinite VC-dim equivalent to say our hypothesis class is a universal approximator (contains all functions)?*

In the case of the sine family, one can see that indeed it has an infinite VC-dim and is a universal approximator. But is it true in general?